# Can an n-th degree multivariable polynomial be equal to a higher degree taylor polinomial?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Recently, I stumbled across the question:

Consider $p(x,y)$ a 5th degree polynomial. Find the correct statement:

1. $p(x,y)$ is equal in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to its 8th degree Taylor polynimial in the point (1,2)
2. 1 is incorrect but $p(x,y)$ is equal in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the 5th degree Taylor polynomial in the point (1,2)

Intuitivly, given a n-th degree polynomial you cannot give a higher than 5th degree taylor polynomial as you'd need higher than n-th order non zero partials which are imposible to get as for every partial you take you lower the degree of $p(x,y)$ by one. Therefore when you get to the n-th order partial you end up with a constant and you can't take any more non zero partials.

However, the answer to the question above seems to be 1. and i don't understand how you could be able to obtain the non zero coeficients for the higher than n-th degree monomials

Comment: I've asked this to my calc II professor, who asked the question on the first place, and he said that despite the coeficients of the 8th degree Taylor polynomial being 0 for all higher than 5-th degree terms it's still considered an 8th degreeTaylor polynomial.

Comment: The crux of the matter is that "Taylor polynomial of degree $k$" need not be a "polynomial of degree $k$." The most basic example is a constant function, say $f = 1$ everywhere. Then $T = 1$ everywhere as well and for all degrees! Yet, $T$ is decisively not a polynomial of degree $k$ even when it is the "Taylor polynomial of degree $k$." A much better name would be "Taylor approximation of $k$th order" for that would mean that $|f(x) - T(x)|$ is of order less than $k.$ In my example of a constant function $|f - T| = 0$ which is of order less than $k$ for every $k$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really have to do with the number of variables; the same thing could happen with a one-variable polynomial. It's a question of terminology - we need to consider that "the $n$-th degree Taylor polynomial" of a function has one definition, and "the degree of a polynomial" has another definition. They often match up, which is why we reuse the word "degree" in the first place, but they don't always have to.

For one dimension, the "$n$-th degree Taylor polynomial" is the polynomial obtained from the partial Taylor series up to the $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n$ term. We can think of this as an algorithm for getting a polynomial, where we always calculate all $n+1$ terms. And if $f^{(n)}(0) \neq 0$, the degree of the resulting polynomial is in fact $n$. But when $f^{(n)}(0)=0$, including the case when $f$ is already a polynomial with smaller degree, the degree of the resulting polynomial is less than $n$.

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for a comment.*

Nothing needs to be added after @aschepler's answers. Where the problem starts to be interesting is when we do series reversion.

Consider the simple
$$y=x+x^2$$ that we shall write as
$$y=x+x^2+O(x^p) \qquad \text{with} \qquad p \geq 2$$ Now, making reversions (even if the results do not mean anything)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \text{inverse series of}\,\, y=x+x^2+O(x^p) \\
 2 & y-y^2+O\left(y^3\right) \\
 3 & y-y^2+2 y^3+O\left(y^4\right) \\
 4 & y-y^2+2 y^3-5 y^4+O\left(y^5\right) \\
 5 & y-y^2+2 y^3-5 y^4+14 y^5+O\left(y^6\right) \\
 6 & y-y^2+2 y^3-5 y^4+14 y^5-42 y^6+O\left(y^7\right)
\end{array}
\right)$$ and if we compute the inverse of these inverses, we get back to $y=x+x^2+O(x^p)$.